# How to make angry birds scoring type "three stars rating" in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I want to make a scoring system that shows star based on points like angry birds.

> if you get:  3 points = 3 stars,   1-2 points = 2 stars, 0 = 1 star

The stars will be an image.
The points will save after answering all of the three questions. The points will appear in the form of star like above. I desperately need this.

Comment: This is very.... vague. we need more info. start with these questions: how are points scored? does each questipn score one point? how do you plan to light up each star? are the stars movieclips or images?

Answer (score 1):

- Create an image for one "lit" star, and one for one "dim" star;
- Place instances of them on the stage, "lit" stars overlapping "dim" stars, but being hidden initially;
- Keep an array with references to the "lit" instance images, and turn visible a number, which is proportional to your score.

Below is something more of a general solution:

```
public class StarsScoring extends Sprite {

    [Embed(source = "path/To/DimImage.jpg")]
    private var _dimStar: Class;

    [Embed(source = "path/To/LitImage.jpg")]
    private var _litStar: Class;

    private const GAP: uint = 10;
    private const GROUP_X: uint = 25;
    private const GROUP_Y: uint = 25;

    private var _litStars: Array = [];
    private var _numStars: uint;

    private function _buildScoringUI(): void {
        var litStar: Bitmap, dimStar: Bitmap, hOffset: Number = GROUP_X;
        for (var i: int = 0; i < _numStars; i++) {
            litStar = (new _litStar()) as Bitmap;
            dimStar = (new _dimStar()) as Bitmap;

            litStar.x = dimStar.x = hOffset;
            litStar.y = dimStar.y = GROUP_Y;
            litStar.visible = false;
            addChild(_dimStar);
            addChild(_litStar);

            _litStars.push(litStar);

            hOffset += (litStar.bitmapData.width + GAP);
        }
    }

    public function StarsScoring(numStars: uint = 3): void {
        _numStars = numStars;
        _buildScoringUI();
    }

    public function updateScore(score: uint, total: uint): void {
        var percent: Number = (score / total);
        var threshold: uint = Math.round(percent * _litStars.length);
        for (var i: int = 0; i < _litStars.length; i++) {
            var litStar: Bitmap = (_litStars[i] as Bitmap);
            litStar.visible = (i <= threshold);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage with this class, is that you can use any number of stars you want, and the scoring will adapt automatically. To use it:

```
var stars : StarsScoring = new StarsScoring (3);
addChild (stars);
stars.updateScore (1,3); // Will "lit" first star image
```

Never tested / compiled this code (will do when I have a chance), but even so, it should point you in the right direction.